# What onomatopoeia for cat steps would be clear for English speaker?

Tags: word-request, onomatopoeia

I need a word to imitate a series of light steps, to indicate that some small creature is walking - a cat, a little child or a small dog.

I used ***'Top-top-top-top-top'*** for that, but it seems not to be clear for English speakers. So, I need a new one.

I've visited a number of sites, but the options they suggest are quite limited. I've thought of:

- ***Tap-tap-tap-tap-tap***
- ***Pat-pat-pat-pat-pat***
- ***Pit-pat-pit-pat-pit-pat***

> If you “[tap](https://grammarhow.com/footstep-onomatopoeia/)” it means you are hitting the floor softly and quickly with your feet or shoes. ...to hit something gently, and often repeatedly, especially making
> short, sharp noises.”

> A “pat” is almost entirely synonymous with “tap.” We can use either to refer to short, sharp sounds that come out of a footstep. However, a “pat” also has one key difference to note.
>
> A “pat” is a quick noise that a foot would make. However, the onomatopoeic word “pat” works best when talking about an open palm or open sole, meaning that most bare feet will use the word “pat” to describe the sound they make.

Based on this description, I tend to choose 'tap', but I'm not confident.

Which one is used usually? Is there a better option?

Comment: Opinion based for sure. Cats walk _very quietly_.  We can use 'pad' as a verb to express quiet stepping. Cats have pads on their paws.

Comment: [According to Norse legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleipnir), "the sound of a cat's footfall" is something that doesn't exist because dwarves took it away to use it to make a magic chain!

Comment: I think the sound of a cat padding along is probably even more "unreal" than [the sound of that tree falling in the forest with no-one to hear.](https://www.nsta.org/q-if-tree-falls-forest-and-theres-no-one-around-hear-it-does-it-make-sound) ***Figments of the imagination**!*

Comment: The ***padding*** of cat paws is much better onomatopoeically than ***pat, [pitter-]patter***, because /d/ is a "softer" consonant than /t/. And don't forget [***Kitty Softpaws***](https://shrek.fandom.com/wiki/Kitty_Softpaws), who has to ***pad*** the bad guys into submission, 'cos she's got no claws!

Comment: in addition to the above examples I've often heard (and said) "pap-pap-pap-pap" as an onomatopoeia, especially on a soft surface where there is very little noise heard at all

Comment: Unfortunately, [the most famous poem in English about the sound of cat feet](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45032/fog-56d2245d7b36c) doesn’t use onomatopoeia.

Comment: The truth is that one sees pad as a verb associated with cats but in fact there is no sound at all. They pad along, as in the pads on their feet.

Comment: IMX, cats that have not been declawed, on a hard floor will actually produce much more noise from the toenail making contact than the foot pad.

Comment: ''Pit-pat-pit-pat-pit-pat'' seems fine to me.

Comment: _pit-pat_ is brilliant, way better than accepted answer imo

Comment: I don't think there is one that is 'usually used', other than pitter-patter for children. Cat's tend to be silent, hence the fog coming in on little cat feed.

Comment: A cat walking **on most surfaces** (glass, stone, wood, etc.) makes no sound at all. They are said to pad along. I already said this but now the question has come round again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A cat’s footfalls *are* proverbially silent… but apparently my cats were never very good with proverbs. (Or maybe they’re both secretly [Gilbert and Sullivan fans](https://youtu.be/h4Wj2yMuTIU)?)

I understand your desire to use “top-top-top”. Something about an onomatopoeia of *dental–open vowel–labial* just feels right. But, as you’ve observed, it won’t work well for English speakers; we’re likely to think of the *word* “top” first, and parse it as onomatopoeia second, if at all!

“Tap-tap-tap” also fails, but for slightly different reasons: “tap” already denotes a sound, a sharper and louder one (as of nails or knuckles on wood) than the soft *thump* of a cat’s steps. (And “thump” on its own suggests a *loud* sound, and you can’t very well use “soft thump-soft thump-soft thump” as your onomatopoeia!)

But you can absolutely **make something up**. I’d say stick with *dental–vowel–labial*, but choose some combination that doesn’t already have a distracting meaning. “Dap-dap-dap” would do nicely, I think. (But not “dab-dab-dab”.)

Reversing it to *labial–vowel–dental* also works, though personally I prefer it the other way. So “pat-pat-pat” is good. And “pad-pad-pad” actually *benefits* from the fact that *pad* is a word, namely the word for the walking surface of a cat’s paw!

Two labials could work, except that “bap” and “bop” (and “bat”) already have meanings suggesting hitting something rather than footfalls, so you should avoid them. Ending with ‹f›, a labial *fricative* instead of a stop, is an option, and it suggests a softer sound to me: I think “paf-paf-paf” is entirely reasonable.

Comment: (Fans of [The High Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_High_Life_(British_TV_series)) would probably alter that to ‘*pif-paf-pof*’ — the name of their fictional Song For Europe entry.)

Answer (score 31):

An existing English word is

> **pitter-patter** noun
>
> : a rapid succession of light sounds or beats : patter

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitter-patter)

This often (most often?) appears in the phrase "the pitter patter of tiny feet", which typically refers to the sound of children.

As such, using this to refer to a cat could possibly cause some confusion.  But I'd wager that most readers would find this acceptable: "I heard the pitter-patter of little cat feet [coming out of the fog]" (bad [poem](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45032/fog-56d2245d7b36c) pun).

Comment: I disagree. Pitter-patter to me suggests many more feet.

Comment: Yeah, pitter-patter is like rain, 2+ children scurrying around.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm not sure how common that interpretation is. It could easily be more than one child's footsteps, but I don't think it's at all uncommon to use it this way.

Comment: @LukeSawczak luckily, your average cat does tend to have twice as many feet as your average human.

Comment: I live in the UK, and to me this does neither suggest singular nor plural of the pitter-patterer.

Comment: @LukeSawczak One of the most common uses of this phrase – in fact, probably by far _the_ most common use, so common that it’s [recorded in dictionaries](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-patter-of-tiny-feet) – is to hint at pregnancies (“Will we be hearing the pitter-patter of tiny feet soon?” and things like that), and by default it refers to just a single child in that scenario, since single-child births are by far the most common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The patter, says your source. Find me a few more feet for the pitter!

Comment: @Luke To me, they are completely interchangeable in terms of the number of (pitter-)patterers. There are lots of hits specifically for ‘pitter-patter of tiny feet’ on Google as well (and surprisingly many for ‘pitter-patter of little feet’, which I don’t find idiomatic at all – perhaps a dialectal thing). To the extent that there’s a difference at all, _pitter-patter_ to me just suggests more frequentativity – that is, faster repetitions. More feet will of course do that automatically, but a more excited child running around will also suffice just fine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, it's not a hill I'd die on. Your last sentence I can agree with. I think one even says it of an overexcited heart, now that I think of it.

Comment: pitter-patter isn't exclusively feet - its also used to denote rain falling.

Answer (score 7):

There doesn't seem to be many onomatopoeiae for the sound of an animal walking, with one exception: horses' hooves make a "clip-clop".

Moreover, in English culture, a cat's footfalls are thought to be *silent*. The exception to this would be when the cat is using its claws to attempt to grip, these would make a "scratching" sound.

A small child, on the other hand, is much noisier. However I wouldn't use a word like "tip-tap", instead I'd say "I heard footsteps outside my room"

Comment: It's not just English culture. In Norse mythology, the [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleipnir) that keeps the wolf Fenrir bound was made magically of six things, including women's beards, fish's breath, and the sound of cats' footfalls, which is why none of these things exists anymore.

Comment: My neighbour's cats make a scrabbling sound when running up the wooden fencing.

Answer (score 5):

On what surface?

On carpet, I would say that any sound effect is a fiction. Instead, I would describe the cat's motion in some way, e.g. it "padded across the carpet" (referring to its footpads rather than the sound).

On a surface that gives a little or has the ability to resound, e.g. walking on cardboard or the lid of an empty plastic bin, I would probably say the "patting" of its feet, or even just say I could hear "its footfalls" or "it walking". Other onomatopoeia could include *whuff* or *creak* depending on the surface.

On hardwood, I would go so far as to say "tapping" as cats will sometimes do with their claws. Especially when they're scrambling to get away from a vacuum cleaner or something. As the definition you found said, a tap is shorter and sharper than a pat.

Comment: It absolutely depends on the surface and the gait. Grass is silent, a hollow wooden surface makes a thumping sound when a cat trots. Etc. etc.

Answer (score 5):

When choosing a word, it helps if it either doesn't mean anything, or means something related to the movement. "Top" has a meaning in English which has nothing to do with sound or movement, which is why it is confusing. There are other options though, and you've chosen some good ones.

"Tap" has a meaning which directly relates to the sound claws make on a surface.

"Pat" has a meaning which directly relates to the sound of a soft paw hitting the ground gently. This might be better for a cat.

"Pit-pat" is a common onomatopoeic way of representing repeated sounds by keeping the same consonants (which really are what represent the sound) and alternating vowels, especially when the sounds are not completely identical. This happens frequently in English - consider also "ding-dong" for the sound of bells, or "clip-clop" for the sound of horse's hooves.

In short, you have options. Choose what works for you.

Answer (score 5):

I really like this one you came up with: *pit-pat pit-pat*

It benefits from sounding like "pitter-patter", so already evokes audiovisuals of small feet and light sounds, but it isn't pitter-patter *exactly*, which would be bad because pitter-patter normally describes the sound of human children feet, especially of energetic human children.

*Pit-pat* perfectly suits a cat stalking in the night, or otherwise naturally being close to silent.

Good creation.

*pit-pat pit-pat* sounds like four-feet, and because of the natural intrinsic pairing caused by flip-flopping vowel sounds, the two pairs of footfalls are already broken up into a slow rhythm. An alternative like *dap-dap-dap-dap* is much more likely to be interpreted as a rapid, hurried succession of sounds.

---

I'm not sure I agree with the websites you reference in your post by the way,

> If you “tap” it means you are hitting the floor ***softly*** and quickly with your feet or shoes

*Tap* definitely makes me think of aggressive loud-noises even when it's not about feet, and when it's about feet specifically I can only think of tap-dancing (very loud and percussive), impatient foot-tapping, or anxious leg bouncing. None of those have the connotations that you want.

Meanwhile *pat* is far more suitable for the kind of sound you want to describe (as your references actually kind of support, "most bare feet will use the word 'pat'" — bare feet are surely quieter and more similar to cat's paws than shoed feet). The onomatopoeic *pat* connotes the stickiness of skin when it contacts the surface too, which dampens the noise (not in a gross or overt way at all, it's just that animal surfaces have thin layers of oils).

Answer (score 3):

Consider that onomatopoeia does not have to be conveyed in a single word, an example that covers the sound and meaning for a wide range of cases would be:

**Faint footfall**

This is not intended necessarily as the phrase you should use (it obviously depends on your context), but an example of how it might be derived:

- I imagined the base action/sound (e.g. "pat", "thud") and
- the quality ("light", "faint"),
- noticed the "f/th" of *thud* and *faint*, eg "faint thud"
- which alliterative repetition gives a "fuh-fuh-fuh-fuh" or
  "fut-fut-fut-fut" that seems similar to the end sound required, and finally
- probably picked up *footfall* for *thud* subconsciously from the
  other answers and the *fuh-fuh* above.

So a similar technique (which is just a normal onomatopoeic algorithm) should produce useful prospects for your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Cats feet are padded, these soft paws are not supposed to make *any* noise especially when their owner, the cat, is crouched low stalking its prey.

Use the expression **tiptoeing** to express how softly and quietly a cat walks. The verb **tiptoe** is often associated with a cat prowling or sneaking up behind someone or something.

> Video: [*Cat **Tiptoes** Towards Owner* and Stops When Watched](https://www.jukinmedia.com/licensing/view/1106497)

A cat stepping on the keys of an instrument was the inspiration for a piece of music

> [Anderson & Roe Piano Duo](https://www.andersonroe.com/mv-the-cats-fugue)
> According to eighteenth-century legend, Domenico Scarlatti received a flash of inspiration **after a cat tiptoed across the royal harpsichord** at the Spanish Court. He composed a fugue, and for the fugue's theme he used the succession of discordant pitches produced by Miss Pussy’s paws. This is our own fugue — a joyous romp over the keys — using the very same theme.

And

> *[Cats walk on their tiptoes](https://www.catster.com/lifestyle/cat-facts-weird-science-cats-paws-feet-toes)*
> Cats are digitigrade walkers, which means that instead of walking on the heels and the balls of the feet like we do, they walk on the balls of the feet and the fingertips.

Answer (score 3):

Is there context that makes it clear?

There is at present simply no stock onomatopoeia in English that connotes cat feet, so no phrase can stand on its own and be immediately recognised as such, the way "arf arf" is stereotypically a dog barking.

But if context explains it before or after, then anything goes.

Answer (score 2):

"With cat-like tread" means 'with silent tread'.  Nevertheless, a cat's tread is audible if the cat is walking on a polished wooden floor with claws slightly extended.  The sound produced is (t..
. . k.     t.. t..   kk.......
t)

Answer (score 1):

My cat's feet go *thumputy bumputy bump thump.*  That's all four of them.

And when she runs she makes the sound of soft-hooved, mini-pony galloping. And she speaks fluent English but with a very heavy cat accent. I understand her perfectly.